# Can you locally map a dynamically loaded JS file (using sourceURL)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I understand this might just be *impossible* but when you're making JS available for easier debugging in devtools via the helpful `//# sourceURL` comment, I'd also like to map it to its respective local file, for easy editing.

Clarification on `#// sourceURL=dynamicScript.js`:

> Note: Notice the "//# sourceURL=dynamicScript.js" line at the end of dynamicScript.js file. This technique gives a name to a script created with eval, and will be discussed in more detail in the Source Maps section. Breakpoints can be set in dynamic JavaScript only if it has a user supplied name.

The sourced file now exists in Sources under "no-domain", and is unable to map to my [workspace's](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) dynamicScript.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your local web app directory to a server path, so that you can live edit the JS file that evaluates some code, but there is no way to map the dynamically generated named script to a file on the system as far as I'm aware.

[image: Workspace Configuration]

If you use `eval` to execute code from a string, adding `//@ sourceURL=dynamicScript.js'` simply tells Chrome to simulate that script being an actual file, so that you can debug etc. The file doesn't actually exist, it's in memory. The dynamic 'file' cannot appear as part of a local workspace because it simply doesn't exist on the system.

[image: Dynamic Script Generated]
[image: Dynamic Script File]